# How can I test to see if a variable has been garbage collected?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to set up a test that will tell me whether a variable exists in memory or not. I'm running into the problem of my nested function preserving the local variable it uses, called "shouldBeDead". Here's my best effort, which doesn't work for me because the "shouldBeDead" variable is still alive:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, isDeadYet);

function isDeadYet ($):void {
    var shouldBeDead = "not dead";

    if (!stage.hasEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN))
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, test);

    function test($):void {
        trace("variable is " + shouldBeDead); // outputs: "variable is not dead"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to test if something exists in memory?

Comment: Use a profiler. For instance FDT or Flash Builder contain a profiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `String` cannot be garbaged collected as there is no new instance created but the value is taken from the constant pool that take care of `String`, `Number`, `int`,etc..

If you create a new `Class`, `Object`, `Array`, etc... these can be garbaged collected and you can trace them with a simple method : putting your instance as a weak key into a dictionnary.

So when garbaged collect occured the key will be deleted from the dictionnary.
Here an example of code for testing, and there live code : http://wonderfl.net/c/uP5T :

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.system.System;

var notGC:Dictionary=new Dictionary(true)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown)

function traceNotGC():void{
        var cnt:int=0
        for (var key:Object in notGC) {
            cnt++
            trace("not garbaged : " + key)
        }
        if (cnt==0) trace("All garbaged")
}
function onKeyDown(e:Event):void{
    System.gc()
    traceNotGC()
}
function test():void{
    var str:String="not dead"  // string taken from the constant pool
                               // there is no allocation done

    var obj:Object={foo:"bar"} // creation of a new object that can be garbaged
    var arr:Array=[0,1,2]      // creation of a new array that can be garbaged

    notGC[str]=true
    notGC[obj]=true
    notGC[arr]=true

    traceNotGC()
}      
test()
```

Comment: The true argument to the new Dictionary constructor tells the dictionary to use weak references (in case you missed that).

Answer (score 1):

Simple technique, similar to Patrick's:

### Test with `useWeakReferences` to See When Object is Garbage Collected

1. Instantiate custom class containing event handler listening to 'ENTER_FRAME' (use weak reference).
2. Instance's handler traces output until the instance reference is set to null from the instantiating object.

---

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var livingObject:LivingObject;


        public function Main () {
            livingObject = new LivingObject(this, true);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killIt);
        }
        function killIt ($) {
            livingObject = null;
            trace('Attempted murder of livingObject.');
        }
    }
}
import flash.events.Event;
class LivingObject {
    public function LivingObject ($main:Main, $immortal:Boolean) {
        $main.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, proveImAlive, false, 0, $immortal ? false : true);
    }
    private function proveImAlive ($) {
         trace(this + ' LIVES!!!!!'); // Output stops when garbage collected.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first shouldBeDead is not out of scope in the code you listed. the output "variable is not dead" is it's correct state.
In AS3 it is correct for your nested function to preserve that variable.

for your other question.
If the var points at an object you can always check it for object == null (if the garbage collector has gotten it it will be null)

There is something else but I can't remember.

Here is a very clear answer on the scope of that nested function.
[Nested Functions, how are they garbage collected in flash actionscript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018040/nested-functions-how-are-they-garbage-collected-in-flash-actionscript-3)

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this (or I'm at least not aware of it), because garbage collection is so arbitrary.  Here is a good article about the flash player garbage collection. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html